# httpd.exe - Entry point not found

Tags: apache, xampp, entrypointnotfoundexcept

I installed the xamp and when I start the apache then it's giving me this kind of error

> The procedure entry `point_controlfp_s` could not be located in the
>   dynamic link library `c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe`

[image: Please see this image]

Does any solution of this kind of problem. Please answer if any solution

Comment: Remove and reinstall xampp

Comment: I have already done this. But it is not resolved.

Comment: ever find whats wrong?